# Field 'id' expected a number but got 'add'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a Django project where I have an API endpoint for adding PC parts, and I'm encountering an issue when trying to access the URL /parts/add. I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'add'.
```

This error seems to be related to my Django model's primary key field, which is an AutoField called 'id.' I'm not explicitly providing an 'id' when adding a new PC part, and I expect Django to generate it automatically.

here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.


class PCparts(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField( primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    release_date = models.IntegerField()  # Unix epoch timestamp
    core_clock = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    boost_clock = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    clock_unit = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    TDP = models.IntegerField(default=0.0)
    part_no = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-price']

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

here is my view

```
from rest_framework import status
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.db.models import Avg
from .models import PCparts
from .serializers import partSerializer  # Import the serializer class
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
from django.db.utils import IntegrityError
# Create your views here.


def list_pc_parts(request):
    # get the optional 'type' query parameter
    part_type = request.GET.get('type', '').lower()
    # if part_type not in ['CPU', 'GPU']:
    #     return JsonResponse({"status": 1, "message": "Invalid type. Valid choices are 'CPU' and 'GPU'."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    # Query PC parts based on the 'type' filter
    if part_type in ['cpu', 'gpu']:
        pc_parts = PCparts.objects.filter(type__iexact=part_type)
    else:
        pc_parts = PCparts.objects.all()

    # Serialize the PC parts data using the serializer
    serializer = partSerializer(pc_parts, many=True)

    # Calculate the average price
    average_price = pc_parts.aggregate(avg_price=Avg('price'))['avg_price']

    # Create the JSON response
    response_data = {
        'status': 0,
        'total': len(serializer.data),  # Use the serialized data
        'average_price': average_price,
        'parts': serializer.data,  # Use the serialized data
    }

    return JsonResponse(response_data)


def get_part_details(request, id):
    try:
        part = PCparts.objects.get(id=id)
    except PCparts.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({"status": 1, "message": "Part not found"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    serializer = partSerializer(part)

    response_data = {
        'status': '0',
        **serializer.data,
    }

    return JsonResponse(response_data)


@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(["PUT"])
def add_pc_part(request):
    data = request.data

    # Check if 'id' is provided in the request data
    if 'id' in request.data:
        return JsonResponse({"status": 1, "message": "'id' field is not allowed in the request data"}, status=400)

   # Check if 'type' is CPU or GPU (case-insensitive)
    part_type = data.get('type', '').lower()
    if part_type not in ['cpu', 'gpu']:
        return JsonResponse({"status": 1, "message": "Invalid type. Valid choices are 'CPU' and 'GPU'."}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    # Serialize the request data
    serializer = partSerializer(data=data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        # Save the new PC Part
        serializer.save()

        # Return the response with the newly generated ID
        return JsonResponse({"status": 0, "message": "New part added", "id": serializer.data['id']}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"status": 1, "message": "Invalid data provided"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def update_pc_part(request, id):
    try:
        # Check if 'id' is provided in the request data
        if 'id' in request.data:
            return JsonResponse({"status": 1, "message": "'id' field is not allowed in the request data"}, status=400)

        # Deserialize the request data using the serializer
        try:
            part = PCparts.objects.get(id=id)
        except PCparts.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({"status": 1, "message": "Part not found"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        serializer = partSerializer(part, data=request.data, partial=True)

        # Validate the data
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return JsonResponse({"status": 1, "message": serializer.errors}, status=400)

        # Save the updated PC Part object
        serializer.save()

        return JsonResponse({"status": 0, "message": "Part details updated"}, status=200)

    except IntegrityError:
        return JsonResponse({"status": 1, "message": "Failed to update PC Part"}, status=500)
```

any help is appreciated THANKS!!!

The issue occurs when I try to access /parts/add, and it seems to be related to how Django handles primary keys and AutoFields.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably its due to the URL configuration. Like you are passing the `id` value in `url`. But in `urlpattern` you didn't mention `id` parameter or you are missing the id value part in the URL.
for example :-
`/parts/add`-> `/parts/<int:pc_id>/add`
or wise-versa

Comment: hi i manage to get it working thank you so much!!